# четырнадцать календарных дней/дня

Tags: грамматика, падежи

правило написания числительных в падеже. Как правильно написать: отпуск сроком на четырнадцать календарных дней или дня?

Answer (score 3):

Отпуск сроком на **четырнадцать календарных дней**.

Четырнадцать дней - это сочетание не меняется, "календарных" - определение, также согласование во мн. числе.

**Примечания**

Для  числительных "два,три,четыре" существительное в счетном обороте используется в форме **ед. числа**: два дня, три недели.

Для этих же числительных возникают проблемы с выбором **падежа (а не числа)** **для прилагательных**:  два **календарных**  дня (Р.п., м.р.), три **последние** недели (В.п., ж.р.).